# Convert a native `asyncio` coroutine into a task that can be submitted to a `concurrent.futures` ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have an async function that I would like to run. For the sake of this question lets say it is:

```
async def __increment_percent_complete(self):
    timeout_start = time.time()        
    duration = 5

    while time.time() < (timeout_start + duration):
        time_since_start = time.time() - timeout_start
        percent_complete = (time_since_start / duration) * 100.0
        self.get_logger().info(f"Percent complete: {int(percent_complete)}%")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    self.get_logger().info("Done!")
```

I then have a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, and my own "event loop" that looks someting like this:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(num_threads)
while True:
    callback: Task = wait_for_ready_callbacks() #return callbacks that are ready to be executed
    executor.submit(callback)
```

How can I turn the native coroutine into a task that can be submitted to the executor?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which I think works:

I simply have a function

```
def __coro_to_callable(self, coro: Coroutine) -> Callable:
    def drive():
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    return drive
```

This can be used to create Tasks that can be submitted to a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and it all seems to work.

Comment: You could also use `asyncio.run()`, e.g. `executor.submit(asyncio.run, coro)`. That is similar to your solution, but with the advantage of properly closing the loop.